# Delete a specific row from the xlsx using java

Tags: java, excel

i am trying to compare the filenames with the xlsx sheet ...if the filename matches with the value of the excel sheet...i want to delete that particular row from the excel sheet....
below is the code what i have tried so far ...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class try2 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        File[] files=  new File
                ("C:\\wamp\\www\\ptry\\sample\\xl").listFiles();
        String s = null;
        for(File file:files){
            s=file.getName();
            s=s.replaceAll(".xlsx", "");
            }
            File xl=new File("C:\\wamp\\www\\ptry\\sample\\xl.xlsx");
            FileInputStream f=new FileInputStream(xl);
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook (f);
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            int row=sheet.getLastRowNum()+1;
            int colm=sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
            for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
                XSSFRow r=sheet.getRow(i);
                String m=cellToString(r.getCell(0));
                if(s.equals(m)){
                    System.out.println(m);
                }
            }
        }


    public static String cellToString(XSSFCell cell) {
        int type;
        Object result = null;
        type = cell.getCellType();
        switch (type) {
            case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                result = cell.getStringCellValue();
                break;
            case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                result = "";
                break;
            case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                result = cell.getCellFormula();
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
    }
```

here 's' is the variable to hold filenames and 'm' is the variable to hold excel values
The PROBLEM is:
if i use

```
   if(s.equals(m))
  {
    System.out.println(m);
  }
```

HOW TO DELETE THE MATCHED ROW FROM THE EXCEL???
Eg)

File names:

a.xlsx

b.xlsx

c.xlsx

excel.xlsx

a

b

d

c

i want to remove a and b from the excel.xlsx

UPDATED:
        Based on YASH suggustion i tried the below code

```
                 if(s.equals(m)){
                    System.out.println(m);
                    sheet.removeRow(r);
                }
```

it removed the first value from excel.xlsx(a)....and shows Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException error in the below line

```
                     String m=cellToString(r.getCell(0));
```

i tried with

```
              XSSFRow r = sheet.getRow(i);
                    if(r==null){
                        continue;
                    }
```

it takes only two values(a,b) from excel.xlsx

Comment: "but it is not working for not equal cases..it shows all values from the excel for not equal cases" That's what it is supposed to do, right? What do you want to accomplish using not equals?

Comment: thanks for your response...sorry for the confusion...when the case is equal i want to delete that row from excel.......

Comment: Well. Do you want help with how to delete the row or are you having problem with the comparison itself?

Comment: YES....i got the file names and excel values and compared the both....the problem is in deleting the matched value from excel..

Comment: i got confused....sorry....question updated...please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got the answer

```
        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.FileInputStream;
        import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
        import java.io.FileOutputStream;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.Iterator;
        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.logging.Level;
        import java.util.logging.Logger;
        import javax.swing.JButton;
        import org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException;
        import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
        import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile;
        import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.Sheet;
        import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
        import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
        import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
        import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
        import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
        import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
        import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
        import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

        public class try1 {
           public static void main(String[] args)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
             File[] files=new File("D:\\aa\\a").listFiles();
                   String s = null;
                                   for(File file:files){
                                    s=file.getName();
                                            s=s.replaceAll(".xlsx", "");  

                    File xl=new File("D:\\aa\\w1.xlsx");
                    FileInputStream f=new FileInputStream(xl);

                   XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook (f);
                    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
                    int row=sheet.getLastRowNum();
                int colm=sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
                for(int i=0;i<row;i++){

                    XSSFRow r = sheet.getRow(i);
                    if(r==null){
                       sheet.getRow(i+1);
                        continue;
                    }
                Cell cell=r.getCell(0);
                String m=cellToString(r.getCell(0));
                if(s.equals(m)){
                  System.out.println("s :"+m);
                   sheet.removeRow(r);

                   }}


                FileOutputStream out= 
            new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\aa\\w1.xlsx"));
               wb.write(out);
                }               
                     }public static String cellToString(XSSFCell cell) {

                int type;
                Object result = null;
                type = cell.getCellType();
               switch (type) {
                 case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    result = cell.getStringCellValue();
                    break;
                case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                    result = "";
                    break;
                case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                    result = cell.getCellFormula();
                }

                return result.toString();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
After removing the row with RemoveRow(r) shift the remaining rows by 1 as shown below to avoid NullPointer Exception

    sheet.RemoveRow(r);   

            int rowIndex = r.RowNum;

            int lastRowNum = sheet.LastRowNum;

            if (rowIndex >= 0 && rowIndex < lastRowNum)
        {
            sheet.ShiftRows(rowIndex + 1, lastRowNum, -1);
        }
```

Comment: ..thanks for your answer....i tried this      if(s.equals(m)){
                sheet.removeRow(r);
                    int rowIndex = r.getRowNum();
                     int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
                     if (rowIndex >= 0 && rowIndex < lastRowNum)
                      {
                    sheet.shiftRows(rowIndex + 1, lastRowNum, -1);
                      }
                       }  still same null exception error :(